# Powershell Array parameter from pipline

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to duplicate a typical powershell -Computername parameter that's available from the pipeline and as a normal parameter using `CmdletBinding` and `ValueFromPipeline`.  My challenge is that I'm getting different results from specifying the parameter versus piping in values.

My code looks like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [string[]]$ComputerName
 )

BEGIN {  "Begin script`n-----" }

PROCESS { 
    "  `$ComputerName '$ComputerName'"
    "  `$_ '$_'"
    "  +++ Count: " + $ComputerName.Count
    foreach($computer in $ComputerName) {
        "    `$computer '$computer'"
    }
    "  -----"
}

END { "Complete" }
```

When I run this using a pipeline, I get this:

```
PS> (1, 2, 3) | .\BPEParamTest.ps1
Begin script
-----
  $ComputerName '1'
  $_ '1'
  +++ Count: 1
    $computer '1'
  -----
  $ComputerName '2'
  $_ '2'
  +++ Count: 1
    $computer '2'
  -----
  $ComputerName '3'
  $_ '3'
  +++ Count: 1
    $computer '3'
  -----
Complete
```

However, when run with a parameter, I get different results:

```
PS> .\BPEParamTest.ps1 -ComputerName (1, 2, 3)
Begin script
-----
  $ComputerName '1 2 3'
  $_ ''
  +++ Count: 3
    $computer '1'
    $computer '2'
    $computer '3'
  -----
Complete
```

Comment: I do hope somebody comes back with a good answer. I've been banging my head against this for a couple days now as well. I noticed that if I don't have Begin/Process/End blocks and just include the code in a basic function it behaves differently as well, so I think it has to do with the blocks.

Comment: So my end result was to kill the pipeline usage, and just go with the parameter based computername array.  This ends up being more along the lines of how several of the built in commands work such as get-service (pipeline is service name, not computername), get-process (pipeline is process name) and test-connection.  These all use Computername with ByPropertyName stuff.  End result is to run this with `-ComputerName (Get-Content Servers.txt)` rather then `Get-Content Servers.txt | `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use the following construction. This works for arrays in a parameter as well as from the pipeline:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [string[]]$ComputerName
 )

process {
  foreach($computer in $computername){
      #do the stuff
  }
```

Full explanation:  The process block is run once for each item in the pipeline, so that's how it handles lists on the pipeline (i.e. $computername is set to each item in turn).  If you pass the values as a parameter, the $computername is set to the list which is why there's a loop.

Comment: This approach is less effective if the collection is large or expensive to gather.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If you pipe in a list of things, the process block is run once for each item. They aren't collected at all. The loop is there for arrays presented on the command-line as arguments.

Comment: And if the collection is expensive and passed as an argument, PowerShell gathers the whole collection before calling the function anyway. (I was thinking about `foreach` rather than the pipeline.)

Comment: Definitely agree about using foreach keyword with big collections.

Comment: So this ends up working (incorrectly) like my example above - when a list of servers is piped to the script, PROCESS is called once per item in the pipeline, when called using the parameter, PROCESS is called once.

Comment: That's why there's a loop.  The loop handles lists passed using the parameter.

Comment: OK - so what I'm seeing is what I'm now considering noise.  With the outputs before and after the ForEach, you get the goofy output.  Making the ForEach the outermost construct makes things work well.

Answer (score 0):

`.\BPEParamTest.ps1 -ComputerName (1, 2, 3)` does not use the pipeline but rather a single input (a 3-element array). In contrast, `(1, 2, 3) | .\BPEParamTest.ps1` uses the pipeline (3 separate inputs).

To work around this, you can check bound parameters and determine if there is pipeline input. Here is a short example:

```
function out-item {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$TRUE)]
      $item
  )
  begin {
    $PipelineInput = -not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("item")
    write-host "Pipeline input? $PipelineInput"
    $n = 0
  }
  process {
    if ($PipelineInput) {
      $_
      $n++
    }
    else {
      $item | foreach-object {
        $_
        $n++
      }
    }
  }
  end {
    write-host "Output $n item(s)"
  }
}
```

With this function, both `1,2,3 | out-item` and `out-item 1,2,3` produce the same output (except for the "Pipeline input?" part).

Comment: Main issue with this is the goofy-ness of having Process run once for parameter and multiple times for pipeline.
You'd also have to have your main processing in a function:
`if ($PipelineInput) {`
      DoStuff -computer $_
    }
    else {
      $item | foreach-object {
        DoStuff -computer $item
      }
    }

What would be ideal is somehow in the begin to convert the parameter to the pipeline.  All of which goes to crap if someone calls it with both pipeline and parameter :-)

Comment: The process block is not a problem (in fact, it's implicit in all functions if not declared). Also, a parameter cannot have both pipeline *and* parameter input in the same invocation; it's either-or by definition.

Answer (score 0):

[Mike Shepard's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24661873/10224443) answer does work. However, if you'd like to *process* only one element at a time in the `process` block I'd recommend the following approach:

1. Determine whether the script receives its input from pipeline or parameter (`$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.ExpectingInput`).
2. If the input is provided by parameter pipe it to the very same script and exit processing (`break`).
3. If the input is provided by the pipeline keep on going.

Full example:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [string[]]$ComputerName
 )

BEGIN {
  if (-Not $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) {
    $ComputerName | & $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName
    break
  }
  "Begin script`n-----"
}

PROCESS { 
    "  `$ComputerName '$ComputerName'"
    "  `$_ '$_'"
    "  +++ Count: " + $ComputerName.Count
    foreach($computer in $ComputerName) {
        "    `$computer '$computer'"
    }
    "  -----"
}

END { "Complete" }
```

The output is the same for

```
PS> (1, 2, 3) | .\BPEParamTest.ps1
```

and

```
PS> .\BPEParamTest.ps1 -ComputerName (1, 2, 3)
```