# PowerShell Module Parameter can't pipe ADUser Array

Tags: powershell

i have the following Situation:
Im trying to create a PS Module to export ADUsers to an excel file as .xlsx file, as a own function.
When i pipe a Get-ADUser command to my Parameter, i do not get the whole users, i do only get the last one.
I have declared the inputvariable as ADAcount Object and also as array..

Hier is my Code in extra short format:

```
Function Export-Excel
{
   [cmdletBinding()]
   param(
       [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
       [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAcount[]] $Users  

   )

   Write-Host $Users.count




...........

}
```

When i now call the function via powershell it looks like:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Export-Excel

# Output: 1
# And this one is an ADUser Object, the last created one / the last one in the array...

# When i do this:
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *
Write-Host $user.count

# Output: 2500
```

I hope you understand my problem :)

Thanks a lot and have nice christmas time :)

Comment: possible duplicate of: [Export users from AD with certain fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69209166/export-users-from-ad-with-certain-fields) or [add exported data from console to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74150594/add-exported-data-from-console-to-csv-file/74151828#74151828)  or [Exporting a list of AD Users and their group through powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74602797/exporting-a-list-of-ad-users-and-their-group-through-powershell)

Comment: I dont know why you flaging this as dublicate.
None ot these questions, answer my question.
I try to create my own excel file in .xls format, what i can autmatic process.
Export-CSV is no option!

Comment: Exporting to Excel is pretty much the same as Exporting to CSV. The most important difference is the final output, which has not very much todo with the selection process in Powershell.

Comment: The problem is not the export. The problem is that i cannot pipeline an array of ADUsers into my inputvariable inside my module. Thats seriously not an dublicate with some of your shared topics!?
The code in the module musst have a problem or its just not working in powershell 5.1... thats what i want to know...

Comment: What are you for a hate person!?

Comment: I did not flag this post as a duplicate....

Comment: 27 min ago, you did!?

Comment: seriously, im just asking me, why you have marked this post as unsueful with the thumb down?
This post can help many others in the world wide web. As you can find NOTHING about this thing in the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pipe all your user objects, import and work with the total (for reporting) you'll need to use the `Begin`, `Process`, and `End` keywords as detailed in `get-help about_functions`, for example:

```
Function Export-Excel {
    [cmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser[]]$Users
    )
    begin {
        $usersArray = @()
    }
    process {
        foreach ($user in $Users) {
            $usersArray += $user
        }
    }
    end {
        Write-Host $usersArray.count
    }
   
}


Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Export-Excel
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats exactly what im searching for! Seriously thanks a lot!!
I had a powershell basic course from microsoft, they dont tell us this structure with begin, process and end....
Is this specific for AD Objects or standard for every array input?

Comment: You're welcome. This is a function thing, they can be quite complex, Microsoft have made several help pages because of this. Have a read of `get-help about_functions` and `about_Functions_Advanced` for a good overview.

Answer (score 0):

I did do, a bit, research, and found: [Powershell Array parameter from pipline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661033/powershell-array-parameter-from-pipline)

Then I changed your script, a little, because I do not have an AD:

```
Function EE
{
   [cmdletBinding()]
   param(
       [parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
       #[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAcount[]] $Users  
       [string[]]$Users   
   )

   process {
       write-Host $Users
   }

}

Get-LocalUser | EE
```

The explanation is: The "process" block is run once for each item in the pipeline.

This will get me a list of all my local users.

Comment: Thanks. Thats also a good explanation after the prev post.